# DFS replication Group Invalid credentials on Domain logon

Tags: dns, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I configured the domain a log time ago, but now I reciving this error, and I dont know where I can change the account and password to test more times. The namespaces can read and write the another server shared folder normally but I really need this replication.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logout ADM server name account and login whit Domain ADM and everthing is working good.